# Selecting a checkbox which has an href link min the label associated with it using selenium web driver

Tags: selenium, xpath, checkbox

I need to select a checkbox using selenium webdriver. When i try o find the xpath, xpath of the checkbox along with the label is getting. I found its xpath and clicked the element.
But the label associated with the checkbox has a link in it. So when i click the element, the link in the label is clicked and gets redirected to another page.

In this case how can i select the checkbox?

Comment: Provide `html` or link for same and code you tried

Comment: <input id="terms_checkbox" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox"/>
<label id="chkterms_lbl" class="css-checklabel radGroup2" for="terms_checkbox">
I am 18 years or older and accept the                                          
<a href="/Terms">terms and conditions</a>
 for having a Unibet account
</label>
<span class="rs-sub">Check the box to accept our terms and conditions</span>

Comment: show `xpath` that you use to click checkbox

Comment: @Amrutha check solution. Simply select element and check if not selected then click on it. I have tested code it is working fine.

Comment: @Anderson Xpath: //*[@id='terms_checkbox']

Answer (score 0):

try following code.

```
var checkBox = driver.FindElement(By.Id("terms_checkbox"));
            if (!checkBox.Selected)
            {
                checkBox.Click();
            }
```

if any issue then let me know.

Comment: Please add your full html. which html you have given in your above comments. i have tried on it and it is working fine.
And one more thing when you open page in browser checkbox is visible or not.

Comment: checkbox is visible when the page is opened in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You should make your element visible before clicking on it, so run `JavaScript` at first. In `Python` this will looks like

```
driver.execute_script('document.getElementById("terms_checkbox").style.visibility="visible";')
```

Also you might need this

```
driver.execute_script('document.getElementById("terms_checkbox").style.display="block";')
```

You have not specified your programming language, so you need to adopt this `Python` code if you use different language

**UPDATE**

I'm not sure, but guess in `Java` this should be something like

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript('document.getElementById("terms_checkbox").style.visibility="visible";');
js.executeScript('document.getElementById("terms_checkbox").style.display="block";');
```

Comment: @Anderson: i'm using Java

Comment: @Anderson: when i included these lines in my code, i got an error in the line js.executeScript('document.getElementById("terms_checkbox").style.visibility="visible";');                                                                                                       The error is "Invalid character constant"